# field trace and product

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $a,b$ be elements in a number field. If the field (Galois) traces of $a,b $ are nonnegative, then is the field trace of $ab $ also nonnegative? Can I find an explicit formula of $Tr (ab) $ from $Tr (a) $ and $Tr (b) $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. For example the trace of $1+i$ is $2$, the trace of $i$ is $0$ but the trace of $i(1+i)$ is $-2$.

About your second question, in principle you can try to write down the formula for the minimal polynomial of $ab$ given the minimal polynomials of $a$ and $b$, which I think, but I'm not 100% sure, can be done via resultants. Then use the fact that the trace is the coefficient of degree $n-1$ of the minimal polynomial, if that has degree $n$. This will give you a formula for the trace of $ab$ which will involve the coefficients of both minimal polynomials of $a$ and $b$, including their traces.

Answer (score 1):

No. Consider $a=b = 1+i\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb Q(i\sqrt{2})$.

We have $Tr(a)=Tr(b)=2$ but $Tr(ab)=-2$.